# How do I use recursion to calculate the greatest common divisor (GCD) of 2 numbers and find the maximum number of modulus operations it took?

Tags: recursion

The program needs to measure the maximum number of modulus operations it took to calculate the GCD of 2 integers at each value of "i" from 8 to n.

For example, if i = 8, I have to find the combination of (a,b) that took the most modulus operations to calculate the GCD.

I have to calculate GCD for all values of 'a' (1-i) for every value of 'b' between (1-i) and do this at every value of "i" until it reaches n.

For example, if n = 15, the output must look like this:

At i = 8; GCD (5, 8) = 1 took 4 modulus operations

At i = 9; GCD (5, 8) = 1 took 4 modulus operations

At i = 10; GCD (5, 8) = 1 took 4 modulus operations

At i = 11; GCD (5, 8) = 1 took 4 modulus operations

At i = 12; GCD (5, 8) = 1 took 4 modulus operations

At i = 13; GCD (8, 13) = 1 took 5 modulus operations

At i = 14; GCD (8, 13) = 1 took 5 modulus operations

At i = 15; GCD (8, 13) = 1 took 5 modulus operations

Here's my code so far because I'm so confused on the implementation:

```
class Euclidean
{
    public: 
        //Finds the GCD using modulus operations until the remainder is 0
        int calcGCD(int x , int y)
        {
            int remainder;

            while(y != 0)
            {
                remainder = x % y;
                x = y;
                y = remainder;
            }

            return x;
        }

        //Calculates the maximum amount of oprations required to calculate GCD
        //at (a,b) for every i from 8 to n
        int CalculateMaxOperations(int n)
        {
            int GCD;
            int a;
            int b;

            for(i = 8; i <= n; i++)
            {
                for(b = 1; b <= i; b++)
                {
                    if( b <= i)
                    {
                        for(a = 1; a <= i; a++)
                        {
                            if(a <= i)
                            {
                                GCD = calcGCD(a, b);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Print statement reveals the set (a,b) that took the most operations to calculate
        //the GCD at every single value 'i' until it eventually reaches 'n.'
        void PrintResults(int c, int d, int operations)
        {
            cout << "At i = " << i << ";" << " GCD (" << c << "," << d << ")" << " = " <<
            calcGCD (c, d) << " took " << operations << " operations " << endl;
        }

    private:
        int i;
};

int main()
{
    Euclidean e;
    int x = e.CalculateMaxOperations(15);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suppose you should start by getting code that compiles.